Refreshing foreign keys and related stuff in WPF DataGrid
I need to show a list of deliveries in a datagrid, using MVVM and Entity Framework in a WPF application. Each delivery has an assigned courier, which can be changed via the dialog EditWindow. It all works well, all info about delivery like name is saved correctly in a database immediately after SaveChanges is called and is refreshing in the datagrid.
The only trouble is that when assigned courier is changed to another one, the courier name does not get refreshed in the datagrid. I have added column with CourierUid data for the test purposes, but even this property is not refreshed in the datagrid. But it is saved in a database correctly as well, and of course all info is refreshed after reopening of my application. No idea what am I doing wrong.
Here is the code:
Delivery class:
public class Delivery : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string nameDelivery = string.Empty;

    string? courierUid = null;

    public string DeliveryUid { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public string NameDelivery
    {
        get { return nameDelivery; }
        set
        {
            nameDelivery = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("NameDelivery");
        }
    }

    public string? CourierUid 
    {
        get { return courierUid; } 
        set
        {
            courierUid = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CourierUid");
            OnPropertyChanged("NameCourierFull");
        }
    }

    public Courier? Courier { get; set; }

    public string NameCourierFull { get { return Courier?.NameCourierFull ?? string.Empty; } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}

Courier class:
public class Courier : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string nameFirst = string.Empty;
    string nameSecond = string.Empty;
    string nameThird = string.Empty;

    public string CourierUid { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public string NameFirst
    {
        get { return nameFirst; }
        set
        {
            nameFirst = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("NameFirst");
            OnPropertyChanged("NameCourierFull");
        }
    }

    public string NameSecond
    {
        get { return nameSecond; }
        set
        {
            nameSecond = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("NameSecond");
            OnPropertyChanged("NameCourierFull");
        }
    }

    public string NameThird
    {
        get { return nameThird; }
        set
        {
            nameThird = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("NameThird");
            OnPropertyChanged("NameCourierFull");
        }
    }

    public string NameCourierFull => $"{NameFirst} {NameSecond} {NameThird}";

    public ICollection<Delivery> Deliveries { get; set; } = [];

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}

DeliveryViewModel (only Edit command which matters here, file is too big):
public RelayCommand EditDeliveryCommand
{
        get
        {
            return editDeliveryCommand ??= 
                new RelayCommand((selectedItem) =>
                {
                    if (selectedItem is not Delivery dbDelivery) return;

                    Delivery delivery = new()
                    {
                        DeliveryUid = dbDelivery.DeliveryUid,
                        NameDelivery = dbDelivery.NameDelivery,
                        CourierUid = dbDelivery.CourierUid
                    };

                    WindowEditDelivery window = new(delivery, Couriers);
                    if (window.ShowDialog() == true)
                    {
                        dbDelivery.NameDelivery = delivery.NameDelivery;
                        Courier? courierNew = db.Couriers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CourierUid == delivery.CourierUid);
                        dbDelivery.Courier = courierNew;
                        db.Entry(dbDelivery).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
                );
        }
}

   

WindowEditDelivery.xaml (dialog window to edit delivery):
<Window x:Class="DeliveryApplication.WindowsEdit.WindowEditDelivery"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DeliveryApplication.WindowsEdit"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Карточка заявки" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="Name Delivery"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Assigned Courier" Grid.Row="1"/>

    <TextBox Text="{Binding NameDelivery}" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxCourier" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
              DisplayMemberPath="NameCourierFull" 
              SelectedValuePath="CourierUid"
              SelectedValue="{Binding CourierUid}"/>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
        <Button IsDefault="True" Click="Accept_Click">OK</Button>
        <Button IsCancel="True">Отмена</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>

WindowEditDelivery class:
public partial class WindowEditDelivery : Window
{
    public Delivery Delivery { get; private set; }

    public WindowEditDelivery(Delivery delivery, ObservableCollection<Courier> Couriers)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Delivery = delivery;
        DataContext = Delivery;
        ComboBoxCourier.ItemsSource = Couriers;
    }

    private void Accept_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = true;
    }
}

MainWindow.xaml:
<Window x:Class="DeliveryApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DeliveryApplication" xmlns:models="clr-namespace:DeliveryApplication.Models" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=models:Courier}"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Deliveries">
        <TabItem.Content>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Menu Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <MenuItem Header="EditDelivery" Command="{Binding EditDeliveryCommand}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DataGridDelivery, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
                </Menu>
                <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridDelivery"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Deliveries}"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          CanUserAddRows="False"
                          Grid.Row="1"
                          Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Uid}"
                                Header="Uid"
                                Visibility="Hidden"
                                IsReadOnly="True">
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding NameDelivery}"
                                Header="Название груза"
                                Width="*"
                                IsReadOnly="True">
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CourierUid}"
                                Header="Courier Uid"
                                Width="*"
                                IsReadOnly="True">
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding NameCourierFull}"
                                Header="Курьер"
                                Width="*"
                                IsReadOnly="True">
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem.Content>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
</Window>

MainWindow.cs:
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private DeliveryViewModel context;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        context = new DeliveryViewModel();
        DataContext = context;
    }
}


Well, turns out answer was simply adding notification to property Courier in Delivery class:
        public Courier? Courier 
    {
        get { return courier; }
        set
        {
            courier = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("NameCourierFull");
        }
    }

That's it, now courier name in DataGrid refresh every time new courier is picked. But funny thing is that if I try to add there OnPropertyChanged("CourierUid") that doesn't help refresh CourierUid. Well I don't need to do it anyway but if anyone knows proper way to make it, I'd still like to know how. Just in case.
